# Nothing is impossible

Tags: logical-deduction

Here's a little logic-puzzle that I've been thinking about for years and I wanted to hear you oppinion:

> If nothing was impossible, wouldn't it be impossible to find something
>   that is impossible?

Comment: I don't frequent this SE, but I don't think opinionated answers are accepted. *"I wanted to hear you oppinion"* Unless, of course, this logic puzzle has a definite answer?

Comment: This is my second post, so sorry if this doesn't meet the rules of this site

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please read [the tour page](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), and yes as said " Questions that are primarily opinion-based" are not accepted. In this case, once you reach [a reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) of 100, you can post [it in the chat room](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)

Comment: I think it depends, what you meant. If by "wanted to hear your oppinion" you meant the *answer* to your puzzle, then yes, it's a bit off-topic (if the answer to your puzzle is opinion-based). If your questions was along the lines of "How do you like my puzzle, how I can I make it better", I think the "opions" are on topic and the question is a *questions* about the puzzle, not *a puzzle*. Could you clarify what you meant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If nothing is impossible, then it is impossible to find something that is impossible.

Therefore, the initial premise, "nothing is impossible", is not true.

Comment: That's exactly what I thougt, but at the same time I don't believe that there is something that is impossible (except for finding something impossible of course)

Comment: A more paradoxical statement would be: "*Can an omnipotent  God create a stone which he could NOT lift?*"

Comment: @JoshuaWeber There are actually many things that are impossible.  This statement is more pointed at the fact that many of the things that people think are impossible actually are not.  I do not desire to enter into a philosophical discussion any more than I already have.

Comment: Joshua, why do you not believe anything is impossible? How about finding a positive integer between 2 and 3?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm talking about meaningful things here, why would you want to find an integer between 2 and 3?

Comment: @JoshuaWeber, Gareth's comment is exactly the point that is being made.  To say "nothing is impossible" is the same as to make Gareth's request.  You're changing your context, and now saying "nothing meaningful is impossible".

Comment: Right. But let's see: Joshua, what sort of thing counts as "meaningful" -- and what sort of impossibility do you have in mind? If, e.g., you consider a statement "meaningful" only when it *says something nontrivial about the world* then by definition "meaningful" statements have to have some empirical content to them. And if you are interested only in *logical* impossibility, then a logically impossible statement ipso facto can't say anything empirical about the universe and therefore can't be "interesting".

Comment: @LeppyR64 Okay let's turn it that way: It is only impossible to find an integer between 2 and 3 because mankind defined an integer as non-decimal number. Same as dividing by zero is considered as something impossible, zero is equivalent to nothing, so why do we even come up with a word for something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Mathematical entities, including integers, exist regardless of mankind's definitions. We only define, not create. Also, there are countless theorems that involve impossibilities. For example, [Arrow's Impossibility Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

(LeppyR64 already gave a perfectly adequate answer, which has quite rightly been accepted. The following is just intended to go a little further.)

"Impossible" is a slippery word. Consider the following statements.

- It is impossible to run at 100mph.
- It is impossible to travel faster than light.
- It is impossible to find a prime number strictly between 7 and 11.
- It is impossible for a bachelor to be married.

The first is about what human bodies happen to be capable of; an analogous statement could be false in the future thanks to genetic engineering, for instance. The second is about the laws of physics; we'd need an entirely different universe for it to fail. The third should be true in any conceivable world, even if the laws of physics were utterly different. The fourth, like the third, is a matter of logical impossibility, but maybe a different sort -- it's just a matter of definition, whose impossibility is immediately visible once you substitute in the definition of "bachelor". (But this also makes it apparent that its impossibility could go away via a change of definitions, which of course could also happen to any of the other statements.)

Anyway, so far as I can tell, *whatever* notion of (im)possibility you use there will be some impossible things (e.g., finding a prime number strictly between 7 and 11). So it shouldn't be a surprise that assuming "nothing is impossible" leads you to a contradiction; assuming very-false things often does.

If you want to find out what philosophers and logicians have said about this stuff, the term you need to look up is "modal logic". If you found your original conundrum head-spinning, be warned that there's much worse out there.